# How do I transfer variables between functions?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been attempting to program a calculator using the tkinter module in Python, and I have made 14 functions corresponding to each number and symbol on the calculator. The code below is for the number `1`, for example.

The program doesn't return the values as it should, however. I use the values from the previous function in further functions as parameters, but they don't seem to go through and I constantly get result `0`.

The variables `a` and `b` correspond to two numbers to be used in the calculation and `num` is a counter for the program to know when to give the number to `a` and when to give it to `b`. I have tried inserting a print in this code and a and b was printing correctly but it seems to be a problem with the return.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
def num1(num,a,b):
    if num == 0:
        a=a+1
        num=num+1
    elif num == 1:
        b=b+1
    return num
    return a
    return b
```

Comment: `return num, a, b`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/return.html Only the first `return` gets evaluated and actually "returned". So the remaining 2 returns will never be executed.

Comment: The problem is none of the values are returned?

Answer (score 2):

Python function only return one value. When you write `return a;return b`, you only return the first occurrence.

What you need to do , is pack those elements and return them as a tuple:

```
def num1(num,a,b):
    if num == 0:
        a=a+1
        num=num+1
    elif num == 1:
        b=b+1
    return num, a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep in mind that the first `return` statement that reaches the work flow causes the end of the current function and returns the value supplied.
the `return a; return b` lines will never be reached, the execution flow returns to the caller after the first `return` statement

Comment: Wrote it the way Return num, a, b however 1+1 is still 0

Comment: it depends on how the function get called, please add an example because the output depends on the input that you supply

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list, dictionary,tuple, variable. But a function can't return multiple times. You can try inserting the values in a list and then return the list.

Comment: How would I use it in another function as separate values though?

Comment: you can again extract values from list to  variables. like a = your_list[0]